# Passing json objects to another html page with onclick event

Tags: html, flask

I want to create a functionality as provided on wikipedia page (which redirects to other wiki page with an on click event on a particular phrase)

My question is :
How do I send the phrase (with the help of json) so as to identify which html page is to be displayed?

For example on clicking Barack Obama on the wikipedia page of america: I should be able to send the string Barack Obama.(after clicking on the phrase Barack Obama). Also,
Barack Obama is not the name of html page to be directed to?

that is,

```
<a href="/about" title="click" >click here /a>
```

how to send 'click' to about.html

P.S. I am using flask framework

P.P.S:

Problem solved

```
<a href="/about#click" >click here /a>
```

Comment: You pass it in the URL. Please be more specific about your issue.

Comment: Your question is still not clear.what you mean by with the help of json ?

Simply you can do it with <a> </a> tag

Comment: How to do  with <a> </a>?

Comment: If you are sending it to a dynamic page, you can create a query string on the base URL of the target, and then load content on the target page based on the text  of the query string

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with JS, especially given your solution, so I removed the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

a href="/about#click" >click here /a>